# Checking if a datetime object in mongodb is in UTC format or not from python

Tags: python, datetime, pymongo, pytz

In `mongodb`, a field called `joining_date` appears as

```
"Sun Dec 19 2010 05:35:55 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
```

This as you see is a UTC date .

But the same field when accessed from pymongo appears as

```
 datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 19, 5, 35, 55, 286000)
```

From python i need to check that the date is in utc format or not.

Problem: I get a strange result as shown below

```
v = datetime(2010, 12, 19, 5, 35, 55, 286000)
v.tzinfo == pytz.utc # Returns False !..why ?
```

How can I get back the original string `Sun Dec 19 2010 05:35:55 GMT+0000 (UTC)` from `datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 19, 5, 35, 55, 286000)` or how can I check if `datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 19, 5, 35, 55, 286000)` is in UTC format or not ?

Comment: is your date stored as a string or date object in mongodb? can pymongo automatically "marshal" the string into a date object?

Answer (score 11):

`datetime` objects returned by pymongo always represent a time in UTC, just as dates stored in MongoDB are always stored as (that is, assumed to be in) UTC.

pymongo can convert your `datetime`s automatically to be time zone aware if you set the `tz_info` flag to `True` when creating your `Connection`. You can then use `datetime`s `astimezone()` method to convert to another time zone if you wish.

Comment: Is `tz_info` flag should be `tz_aware`?

Comment: @alswl,  ```tz_info``` should be True.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the PyMongo documentation:

> All datetimes retrieved from the server (no matter what version of the driver you’re using) will be naive and represent UTC.

i.e. `v.tzinfo is None`.  You would have been warned about this if you'd tried to convert them to another timezone:

```
>>> v.astimezone(pytz.timezone("US/Eastern"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
```

However, you can get a timezone aware datetime by doing `datetime(v.year, v.month, v.day, v.hour, v.minute, v.second, v.microsecond, pytz.utc)`.  In this case, your original code would work:

```
v = datetime(2010, 12, 19, 5, 35, 55, 286000, pytz.utc)
v.tzinfo == pytz.utc # Returns True
```

Comment: I'm not sure what version of the pymongo documentation you're reading, but since 1.8, pymongo has optionally supported returning timezone-aware `datetime`s. In the current version (2.0), you can set this when creating a `Connection` with the `tz_aware` parameter (accepts boolean). When `tz_aware` is `True`, all `datetimes` are still returned in UTC, but have `tzinfo` set to a fixed-offset (of 0).